# C++ does the iterator need to be deleted?

Tags: c++, memory

I have a question concerning the release of memory

I'm iterating over a vector in one of my programs. Something like this:

```
// init vector
vector<int>* v = new vector<int>();
// iterate
for (vector<Column>::iterator it = v->begin(); it != v->end(); ++it) {
    // do something with it
}
// delete vector
delete v;
```

However I feel unsure, if I should instead write:

```
// init vector
vector<int>* v = new vector<int>();
// iterate
vector<Column>::iterator it = v->begin()
for (; it != v->end(); ++it) {
    // do something with it
}
delete it;
// delete vector
delete v;
```

or is freeing the iterator not necessary, because of freeing the iterator?

Comment: No. Never call delete on iterators.

Comment: Simpler rule: never call delete (or new) at all on anything, at least until you reach the advanced class.

Comment: You shouldn't `new` up an `std::vector` or any of the containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only call delete on the object the iterator is holding, not the iterator itself; using your code as an example (but slightly modified):

```
std::vector<int*> *v = new std::vector<int*>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    v->push_back(new int(i));
}
std::vector<int*>::iterator it = v->begin();
for (; it != v->end(); ++it) {
    // do something with it
    delete *it; // <- notice the deference to delete the underlying int 
    //delete it; // causes compiler error (expected pointer)
}
// delete vector
delete v;
```

Calling delete on an iterator type should generate a compiler error (depending on compiler/implementation etc.).

Comment: "Calling delete on an iterator type should generate a compiler error." -- No, not necessarily. A vector's iterator type can be a raw pointer.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience you never delete an iterator. On top of that iterators only need a minute amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are **not owning** (observing). They are "produced" for a container but are not actually the object that holds the memory. Hence you not only needn't, but also **must not** delete them.

On the other hand you can and **should deallocate through iterators** when your container allocates memory for the objects it holds. An example

```
vector<int*> v(10);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), []() { return new int; });
```

Then one way to deallocate memory for all objects in `v` is to do

```
for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++)
{
    delete *i; // deleting through the iterator - we're not deleting THE iterator
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the general rule about iterators that others have explained, in the case of the code you put up there, the iterator is a stack variable whose scope is local to the block where it's declared (and that is almost always how you declare iterators) , so deleting it wouldn't make any more sense than deleting any other stack variable that gets cleaned up when it goes out of scope. You only call`delete` on something you allocated with`new`.

*Also somewhat relevant here:* You wrote `vector<int>* v = new vector<int>()`, which means v is a pointer and allocated on the "heap" (free-store) so you need to delete it explicitly. But in your example you only used`v`locally, so you have no reason to use a pointer at all and you shouldn't be using one. Just write `std::vector<int> v;` and use it directly: `it = v.begin()`, as @keyser explained, and just as you're actually doing with the iterator. When you do so, you no longer call `delete v;` `v`will get cleaned up automatically when it goes out of scope, just like`it`is cleaned up now.

Maybe you need to read up a bit on [**RAII**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), one of the fundamentals of good C++ programming. If you're coming from a Java or Delphi or C# background, it is a novel concept because in those languages all you get are references to objects on the heap (or where-ever the compiler and run-time decide to put them) but that's not the case in C++. You should learn to take advantage of this feature as much as possible in your C++ code. In C++, pointers to objects should be the exception, not the rule.